# JavaScript GetElementById Change Display When Class Set to Display None

Tags: javascript, html, css

When setting a div to `display:none` using it's ID as the identifier I can then use JavaScript to set `display:block` and hence have buttons to toggle between divs. However when I use the class as the identifier to set `display:none` I cannot toggle them to `display:block` using their unique IDs.

In other words, I want to set a lot of divs to be hidden using their class name, then individually make them visible using their IDs. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: You certainly can do that but it's impossible to say why your code doesn't if you don't actually show it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reason you can't do that?

Not that I know

```
<p class="blahs" id="blah1">1</p>
<p class="blahs" id="blah2">2</p>
<p class="blahs" id="blah3">3</p>
```

---

```
hideme = document.getElementsByClassName("blahs");
for (var i = 0; i < hideme.length; i++) {
    hideme[i].style.display = "none";
}

showme = document.getElementById("blah1");
showme.style.display = "block";
```